# why can't import pandas after installed successfully?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have installed pandas with command 'pip3.4 install pandas'.

```
Successfully installed pandas python-dateutil pytz numpy six
Cleaning up...

root@hwy:~# python3.4
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Why can't import pandas in python3.4 after pandas been installed successfully?

```
root@hwy:/home/debian8# pip3.4 show pandas
---
Name: pandas
Version: 0.17.1
Location: /usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, pytz, numpy
root@hwy:/home/debian8# echo "import sys; print sys.path"
import sys; print sys.path
root@hwy:/home/debian8# python3.4
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: Did you install the packages under root? Either way make sure the location is the same: `pip34 show pandas && echo "import sys; print sys.path" | python`. Hopefully its a just a  simple case of not looking in the right place.

Comment: Because it's illegal http://wwf.panda.org/about_our_earth/species/problems/illegal_trade/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `pandas` is installed here:

```
/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

But this path is not in `sys.path`.

As a workaround do:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

and inside this terminal start Python again and do your import of `pandas`.

If this works, add this line above (`export PYTHONPATH...`) to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent if you use a different shell for a more permanent solution.

Comment: export PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%:/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages

Comment: Updated my answer with the proper way to set the  PYTHONPATH using bash.

Comment: I use python 3.9 and I don't know how to do.