# Cannot Import Pandas in Python3.6.5

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed pandas successfully in Terminal using the command: sudo pip3 install pandas.  The installation information is shown as below:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages (0.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.9.0 in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2011k in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2018.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) 
(1.11.0)
```

When I import pandas in Python 3.6 or 2.7, the result is the same error: No module named pandas. 
According to 
[why can't import pandas after installed successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839960/why-cant-import-pandas-after-installed-successfully)

I have typed in the following code in Terminal but they do not work.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/python3.6/lib/site-packages
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's confusing what you are trying to do. and `sudo` should not be necessary as a user, but just do one thing with one version of python at a time. for python3.6 have you tried `python3.6 -m pip install pandas --upgrade` ?

Comment: Use https://www.kaggle.com/ . Also you can reach your code anytime any computer that connect internet

Comment: I ignored the warning : If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag, everything is OK when I use the command: sudo -H pip3 install pandas. Thank you very much @davedwards@İhsan Cemil Çiçek

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jupyter Notebook? What happens is, that you might have an virtual evironment, that has no Jupyter Notebook installed. After calling it from your current environment, it goes to the base environemnt and searches for it there. And if the search is succesfull, Jupyter will open, but in another environment, that maybe has no Pandas.

Comment: I have not used Jupyter Notebook, I just want to import pandas in python3.6 but it dose not work. @Auss

Comment: I solved it By typing in : sudo -H pip3 install pandas. Thank you very much.